# How to get a generated id stored in localStorage in an Iframe?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I'm currently struggling with authentication on an application. The thing is that I need to get some authentication id from another application that is not in my domain. This could be easily solved if I was able to make a post request to that application and get in return that authentication id (glbid in my case).

I am able to perform that post request, but that would only work for authentication using the other app form. Since they also provide facebook / gmail login, what I'm trying to do is to read the glbid generated on that page after the login is executed.

I also know that the glbid that I need is located in localStorage on that page.

What I'm currently doing is loading an Iframe on my page with the link of that application login page. After the login via Iframe, I was hoping that I'd be able to access localStorage.

After some research, I've found out postMessage. It would work fine for some Iframe that I could have minimal control, but since the link that I'm embedding to Iframe is not in any case under my domain, I'm stuck!

Here's how I access the glbid via chrome console on the application domain login page:

```
JSON.parse(window.localStorage['ca.vc.data.glbid']).value;
```

As a result, I get the glbid. But I want to do that via Iframe. How can I do that? Can someome please support me, or if that is not possible via Iframe, show me another way to reach the same result?